# How many types of report can we generate it with cucumber + java + maven?

Tags: java, report

I want to generate the report without Jenkins just like Extent report.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the *maven-cucumber-reporting* plugin? This produces some really good [interactive reports](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=masterthought%20cucumber%20reporting&source=lnms&tbm=isch).

Here are the POM changes:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
    <version>3.20.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>execution</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <projectName>My Tests</projectName>
                <inputDirectory>target/cucumber</inputDirectory>
                <jsonFiles>
                    <param>cucumber.json</param>
                </jsonFiles>
                <outputDirectory>target/cucumber/report</outputDirectory>
                <parallelTesting>false</parallelTesting>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Here's the test runner:

```
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {
                "pretty",
                "html:target/cucumber/html",
                "json:target/cucumber/cucumber.json",
                "junit:target/cucumber/cucumber.xml",
        },
        features = {"src/test/resources/features"})
public class RunCukesTest {
}
```